# T-SQL trigger for multiple items - multiple updates does not work as i expected

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, updates

Excuse my sql code as my experience is still somewhat lacking.

I have a trigger to update data in a column of another table even if multiple inserts are made. The trigger works but only for 1 item even if i insert two records. I hade added a select of the memotemp and a select of the trigger query and they show the number of items i expect (2 records for the memotemp table) and (1 records for a select of the trigger query, because 1 order number is added to the memo field and there for it still shows the select of 1 records because of the where statement) just as i expected. What stumps me if why it doesn't update the memo column twice if it has 2 records. The method of joining the inserted with the appropriate table for a delete trigger works perfectly, always deletes as many records as expected one or several at once.

This is the trigger code.

```
-- insert production order number into purchase order internal memo
select 
    i.vrr_order_id, i.purchase_order_id
into #memotemp
from inserted i
update po
    set po.internal_memo = isnull(po.internal_memo, '') + 
        case when po.internal_memo is null then (select convert(nvarchar(20), vo.order_number)
                                                 from vrr_order vo 
                                                 where vo.vrr_order_id = t.vrr_order_id)
                                           else (po.internal_memo + ' ' + (select convert(nvarchar(20), vo.order_number)
                                                                           from vrr_order vo 
                                                                           where vo.vrr_order_id = t.vrr_order_id))
                                           end
from purchase_order po  
join #memotemp t on po.purchase_order_id = t.purchase_order_id
where isnull(po.internal_memo, '') not like '%' + 
        convert(nvarchar(20), (select vo.order_number 
                               from vrr_order vo 
                               where vo.vrr_order_id = t.vrr_order_id)) + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, nor exactly how your tables relate to each other, but your query can be written much more simply

```sql
update po
set po.internal_memo =
    concat(
      po.internal_memo,
      po.internal_memo + ' ',
      vo.order_number
    )
from purchase_order po
join inserted t on po.purchase_order_id = t.purchase_order_id
join vrr_order vo on vo.vrr_order_id = t.vrr_order_id
where isnull(po.internal_memo, '') not like '%' + convert(nvarchar(20), vo.order_number) + '%';
```

Assuming your join condition is not unique, you cannot aggregate using multiple rows in a joined update. SQL Server will only use a single row to update, and ignore the rest. Exactly which row it uses is arbitrary. This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#n-using-the-update-statement-with-information-from-another-table).

Instead, aggregate first. I'm guessing here, because I don't have your table schema

```sql
update po
set po.internal_memo = vo.order_number
from purchase_order po
join inserted t on po.purchase_order_id = t.purchase_order_id
cross apply (
    select
      order_number = string_agg(vo.order_number, ' ')
    from vrr_order vo
    where vo.vrr_order_id = t.vrr_order_id
    group by vo.vrr_order_id
) vo
where isnull(po.internal_memo, '') not like '%' + convert(nvarchar(20), vo.order_number) + '%';
```

Comment: What i am trying to do is: when a (or multiple) row(s) in another table (purchase_need) are updated with a purchase_order_id, update the purchase_order (table) internal_memo (column) with however many unique (hence the where statement) order_numbers (contained in the purchase_need table, they always have an order_number and get updated with a purchase_order_id to connect).

Comment: I suggest you show your full table schema, along with sample data and expected results, as I'm still unsure exactly how you want this. i must say, I'm unclear why you need a trigger at all to store this information, why not just query it when you need it from the original table?